# Cocoa: How to properly release NSWindowController after fading out its window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a Cocoa application which presents a startup screen. After collecting some information from the user I check and see if it's valid - if it is I display a green checkmark then wait 1 second and crossfade the startup window into my main application window. I have 2 NSWindowControllers with 2 Window xib files.

On my `startupWindowController` I have a button outlet set up which does what I described above.

```
- (void)fadeOutAndPresentMainWindow {

    // Initialize the main window from XIB
    mainWindowController = [[MyMainWindowController alloc] init];
    NSWindow *mainWindow = [mainWindowController window];

    // Position the main window BEHIND the currently visible startup window
    NSWindow *startupWindow = [startupController window];
    [mainWindow setFrame:[startupWindow frame] display:NO];
    [mainWindow orderWindow:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:[startupWindow windowNumber]];

    // Now wait 1 second and fade out the startupWindow to reveal the main window
    // that is behind it.
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
        [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{

            // releases when closed
            [startupWindow close];

            // deallocates the startup controller *after* the animation? or not...
            [startupWindowController release]; 
            startupWindowController = nil;
        }];

        // Do the fade
        [[startupWindow animator] setAlphaValue:0.0f];
        [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

        // Now make the main window key
        [mainWindow makeKeyWindow];
    });
}
```

This all works great, with one problem: If the user clicks a button with an `IBOutlet` *during* the fade animation the application crashes.
`MyStartupController performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x102c00a90`. So the problem is that the `startupController` is being deallocated before the animation is complete.

So I guess I'm not sure how to properly release this window controller after fading it out. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: If it releases then retain it, create a strong pointer to hold around the object for a while until the animation completes.

Comment: I am releasing it after the animation completes. The completion block does not appears to be invoked at the proper time.

Comment: Better to just not use splash screens...

Comment: While I agree that splash screens are overused and often not necessary there are still valid use cases for them. I believe that my app warrants one. In addition, this question is perfectly valid in other use cases that don't involve a splash screen; a Login screen for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Better place to declare the same in your dealloc method:-
- (void)dealloc
{
[startupWindowController release];
startupWindowController=nil;
}
```

Comment: The class where u have initialized the windowcontroller instance